# Speeding up Message Hub Kafka Java Console sample

Tags: message-hub

I've been working with the Message Hub sample code found at this link: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/message-hub-samples

In particular, I've been trying to increase the throughput of the producer with the Kafka Java console example. I noticed the documentation in this snippet of code:

`// Synchronously wait for a response from Message Hub / Kafka on every message produced.
                    // For high throughput the future should be handled asynchronously.
                    RecordMetadata recordMetadata = future.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    producedMessages++;`

I've already turned off the thread sleep found later in the code which also helped increase the throughput, but I was hoping I could get some help on implementing the future asynchronously in this block. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two basic options for handling the outcome of a produce request asynchronously

1) use the overloaded `send` with a completion callback argument, which will be invoked asynchronously:
`public Future<RecordMetadata> send(ProducerRecord<K, V> record, Callback callback);`

if using the callback you may ignore the future.

2) pass the `Future` to some other thread you have created, and have it inspect the future for completion, while leaving the thread that calls `send` free to carry on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will implement this.